# How to get rid of this command-line argument error?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I wrote a program in c++ which is supposed to take a couple of command line arguments the first of which is an integer and the remaining three are floating point numbers. The part of code that deals with that looks like that:

```
_tmain(__in int argc, __in PZPWSTR argv)
{


    USHORT X, Y, Z, ZR, XR;                         // Position of several axes
    JOYSTICK_POSITION   iReport;                    // The structure that holds the full position data
    BYTE id=1;                                      // ID of the target vjoy device (Default is 1)
    UINT iInterface=1;                              // Default target vJoy device
    BOOL ContinuousPOV=FALSE;                       // Continuous POV hat (or 4-direction POV Hat)
    int count=0;
    DOUBLE Xr, Yr, Zr;


    // Get the ID of the target vJoy device
    if (argc>1 && wcslen(argv[1]))
        sscanf_s((char *)(argv[1]), "%d", &iInterface);

    sscanf_s((char *)(argv[2]), "%d", &Xr);
    sscanf_s((char *)(argv[3]), "%d", &Yr);
    sscanf_s((char *)(argv[4]), "%d", &Zr);

_tprintf("Acquired: X %d\nY %d\nZ %d\n", Xr, Yr, Zr);

the rest of the code ...}
```

My problem is that when I call the program in command line by writing

```
name.exe 1 15 16 17
```

I get Xr = 15 but Zr = 16 and Yr is just some seemingly random huge negative number.

I know this is probably some very basic error, but I've not been able to find to what the was. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is this preprocessed `c++`? Why is `main` not `main`?

Comment: @Rubens: It's MS-specific stuff (both the `_tmain` and the `PZWSTR` for `argv`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `%lf` conversion to read a double. The `%d` you're currently using is only for `int`s.

Comment: Not exactly, `%f` is for `float`s, `%lf` is for `double`s.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier: Oops -- quite right. Thanks. (Always get confused when the same conversion is for a different type with `printf` than `scanf`).